# Prepending lines of output with contents of a shell variable in CYGWIN

Tags: bash, sed, cygwin, environment-variables, prepend

I'm using cygwin bash on a windows64 machine with windows 7.

I have the results of a grep to which I want to PREpend a string (the name of the file).  This grep is the termination of a short series of pipes.

```
#!/bin/sh
for d in `ls extracted_xmls`
do
    if [ -d "extracted_xmls/$d" ]; then
        echo $d
    fi

    if [ -f "interim/$d.txt" ]; then
        rm "interim/$d.txt"
    fi

    for f in `ls extracted_xmls/$d`
    do
        cat "extracted_xmls/$d/$f" | \
            tr "\n" "|" | \
            grep -o "<?GOVINT.*<?GOVINT" \
        >> "interim/$d.txt"
    done
done
```

This works, but I want to prepend the name of the file to the output.
Using the -H switch doesn't work (because input is standard input by that point).

I'm trying to just get a smaller example to work from the command line first instead of running the entire batch file.

I tried using something like:

```
 cat out150106.csv | sed  "s/^/ho/"
```

This works!  However, I want to do something like this:

```
 cat out150106.csv | sed  "s/^/$PATH/"
```

($PATH is just a convenient variable, that's not the actual variable I want to use in the program above.)

When I attempt this, cygwin bash reports:
    *sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown option to `s'*

From what I can tell from googling around, this sort of thing seems to work in other versions of Unix.  (Similar issue with using awk by the way.)

How can I do this in cygwin bash?

As requested, I am including sample input and output files.
Sample Input: (path/ filename is "ipg140107/2014_G_08622343.xml")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v44-2013-05-16.dtd" [ ]>
<us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.4 2013-05-16" file="US08622343-20140107.XML" status="PRODUCTION" id="us-patent-grant" country="US" date-produced="20131224" date-publ="20140107">
    <us-bibliographic-data-grant>
     .... buncha stuff
    </us-bibliographic-data-grant>
    <description id="description">
         ... more stuff ...
        <?GOVINT description="Government Interest" end="lead"?>
        <heading id="h-0002" level="1">FEDERALLY SPONSORED RESEARCH</heading>
        <p id="p-0003" num="0002">The invention was made with Government support under HR0011-07-C-0075 awarded by DARPA. The Government has certain rights in the invention.</p>
        <?GOVINT description="Government Interest" end="tail"?>
        ... bunch more stuff ...
</us-patent-grant>
```

The output I'm looking for would be:

```
ipg140107/2014_G_08622343.xml:<?GOVINT description="Government Interest" end="lead"?>
            <heading id="h-0002" level="1">FEDERALLY SPONSORED RESEARCH</heading>
            <p id="p-0003" num="0002">The invention was made with Government support under HR0011-07-C-0075 awarded by DARPA. The Government has certain rights in the invention.</p>
            <?GOVINT
```

Note that I don't care that the GOVINT processing instruction is incomplete. This is an interim file and that information is superfluous.
There are thousands of input files like this in each directory.  I need to grep each file and append the grep to the same output file (one file for each directory).

Comment: seems your variable content content special character from a sed regex point of view. Maybe a small set -vx just before to have the excat context

Comment: `$PATH` invariably contains `/`s which will terminate the `s/...` command in sed so that could be a very bad choice of surrogate for trying to tell us whatever your real variable can contain.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by cleaning up the script do be more robust/efficient/shell-like:

```
for d in extracted_xmls/*
do
    if [ -d "extracted_xmls/$d" ]; then
        echo "$d"
    fi

    if [ -f "interim/$d.txt" ]; then
        rm "interim/$d.txt"
    fi

    for f in "extracted_xmls/$d"/*
    do
        tr "\n" "|" < "extracted_xmls/$d/$f" |
            grep -o "<?GOVINT.*<?GOVINT" \
        >> "interim/$d.txt"
    done
done
```

Now edit your question to show some sample input and expected output and we can work on modifying it to do whatever it is you want.

Given what you've now told us, change your script to:

```
for d in extracted_xmls/*
do
    if [ -d "extracted_xmls/$d" ]; then
        echo "$d"
        awk 'f; /<\?GOVINT/{if (!f) print FILENAME, $0; f=!f}' "extracted_xmls/$d"/* > "interim/$d.txt"
    fi
done
```